# Manual migration with MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data, migration, magicalrecord

I'm implementing a migration of my CoreData store, where I replace a string attribute with a BOOL attribute: when the string was "0", the bool should be "YES", and in all other cases the bool should be "NO". Sounds simple enough, but I think I still need to add a mapping model. I added that in Xcode, and implemented `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance`:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping: (NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
{
   NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[mapping destinationEntityName] inManagedObjectContext:[manager destinationContext]];

   NSString *oldValue = [sInstance valueForKey: @"oldString"];
   NSNumber *newValue = @(NO);

   if ([oldValue integerValue] == 0)
      newValue = @(YES);

   [newObject setValue: newValue forKey: @"newBool"];

   [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:newObject forEntityMapping:mapping];

   return YES;
}
```

However this never gets called.

Since I'm using MagicalRecord, I also am using:

`[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: @"storename.sqlite"];`

I read I also need to use: `NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @(YES), NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @(NO)};` when I init my store, but how do I use that with MagicalRecord?

UPDATE: So MR uses `MR_autoMigrationOptions` to set the migration options. Is there any way to modify these to support a manual migration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform a manual migration you will need to use:

`[MagicalRecord setupManuallyMigratingStackWithSQLiteStoreNamed: @"storename.sqlite"];`

Comment: I don't have that in MR, which version are you using ?

Comment: [MagicalRecord Version 3](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/release/3.0)

Comment: That's an unreleased version, and I'm hesitant to use it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: For what it's worth I've been using it for a few months now and it's been solid. Having said that, I have not tried the manually migrating stack.

Comment: Prompted by an excellent new book on CoreData for iOS by Tim Roadley, I actually made the decision this weekend (before you answered today) to not use MR for now. I am forcing myself to better understand Core Data by interacting with it directly, not through a framework. Once I do better understand it, I may go back to MR. Thanks again for your insight.